# Standardize the text in the pandas column with some common string

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, text-processing

I have following DataFrame df

```
id1     id2     text_column
key1   220       ABC corp
key1   220       ABC Pvt Ltd
key2   300       PQR Ltd
key2   300       PQR
key2   300       PQR something else
key2   400       XYZ company
```

I don't know what kind of text will be in the Text_Column, but for the same id1 and id2, I want to identify the similar strings in the "text_column" and replace those strings with the standard text.I want text in the text_column to be standardized something similar to below

```
id1     id2     text_column
key1   220       ABC corp
key1   220       ABC corp
key2   300       PQR
key2   300       PQR
key2   300       PQR
key2   400       XYZ company
```

to compute the similarity score i m using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import process,fuzz

df=pd.DataFrame(data={"id1":["key1","key1","key2","key2","key2","key2"],"id2":[220,220,300,300,300,400],"text_column":["ABC corp","ABC Pvt Ltd","PQR Ltd","PQR","PQR something else","XYZ company"]})

filters=['id1','id2']
df_text_column=df.groupby(filters)['text_column'].apply(list).reset_index().rename(columns={"text_column":"lst_text_column"})
lst_temp=df_text_column.columns.difference(df.columns).union(filters).to_list()
df = pd.merge(df, df_text_column[lst_temp], on = filters, how = 'left')
df['text_column smilarity score']=df.apply(lambda x:process.extract(x['text_column'],x['lst_text_column']),axis=1)
df['text_column smilarity score']=df['text_column smilarity score'].apply(lambda x:[i[1] for i in x])
df['text_column smilarity score min']=df['text_column smilarity score'].apply(lambda x:np.min(x))
```

I would like the text in the text_column to be standardized for the similar strings in the same way as mentioned above.This way I would be able to use the text_column in groupby to perform further computations

Comment: Doesn't your code already do this? You could take the first item from `lst_text_column`.  You can also use `.extractOne` instead of `.extract` - and use `score_cutoff=50` to supply a minimum threshold.

Comment: It computes the score but I would like to replace similar strings in the text_column with 1 standard string i.e "ABC corp" and "ABC pvt Ltd" with "ABC".Also the similarity score between  "ABC corp" and "ABC pvt Ltd" is 53 with the above code.I was just wondering if I can modify it in a way that will recognize ABC corp and ABC Pvt Ltd are lot similar compared to the score 53

Comment: `scorer=fuzz.partial_ratio` gives a score of `62` (but less for other cases). This is the output of your code with that scorer: https://bpa.st/raw/DSQF4 - If all the scores are above `X` - you can pick one of the items from `lst_text_column` as the "standard string"? (Perhaps you could run multiple scorers and take the max)

Answer (score 0):

[rapidfuzz](/questions/tagged/rapidfuzz) is worth trying for this type of thing.

If you compare all of the strings at once using its [`.process.cdist`](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/process.html#cdist) - it performs much better compared to other approaches.

`workers=-1` will use all CPU cores.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(scores)
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  1.000000  0.621212  0.422619  0.000000  0.453704  0.621212
1  0.621212  1.000000  0.589610  0.474747  0.445286  0.393939
2  0.422619  0.589610  1.000000  0.866667  0.664021  0.411255
3  0.000000  0.474747  0.866667  1.000000  0.805556  0.000000
4  0.453704  0.445286  0.664021  0.805556  1.000000  0.528620
5  0.621212  0.393939  0.411255  0.000000  0.528620  1.000000
```

The result will be a "matrix" of all the scores, but we can use `.groupby().indices` to figure out the values for each group.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(scores)
          0         1         2         3         4    5
0  1.000000  0.621212       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
1  0.621212  1.000000       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
2       NaN       NaN  1.000000  0.866667  0.664021  NaN
3       NaN       NaN  0.866667  1.000000  0.805556  NaN
4       NaN       NaN  0.664021  0.805556  1.000000  NaN
5       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  1.0
```

From this result we can see our "groups" are rows:

- `0, 1`
- `2, 3, 4`
- `5`

i.e. the indexes of the non-nan columns

Full code example:

```
import rapidfuzz
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({
   "id1": ["key1", "key1", "key2", "key2", "key2", "key2"],
   "id2": [220, 220, 300, 300, 300, 400],
   "text_column": [
      "ABC corp", "ABC Pvt Ltd", "PQR Ltd", "PQR",
      "PQR something else", "XYZ company"
   ]
})

keys = ["id1", "id2"]

min_score = 0.6

scores = (
   rapidfuzz.process.cdist(
      df["text_column"], 
      df["text_column"], 
      scorer=rapidfuzz.distance.JaroWinkler.similarity, 
      workers=-1
   )
)      

col_indexes = np.arange(scores.shape[0])

# indices of values to "remove" - will set to NaN
mask = (
   [np.repeat(rows, len(cols)), np.tile(cols, len(rows))]
   for key, rows in df.groupby(keys).indices.items()
   for cols in [
      np.setdiff1d(col_indexes, rows) # indexes to discard per-row
   ]
)

rows, cols = zip(*mask)
rows = np.hstack(rows)
cols = np.hstack(cols)

# "remove" non-group values
scores[rows, cols] = np.nan

# "remove" any matches below score
scores[scores < min_score] = np.nan

# get the indices of remining matches
row, col = np.where(~np.isnan(scores))
matches = pd.DataFrame(dict(row=row, col=col)).groupby("row").agg(tuple)

df["standard"] = df.groupby(matches["col"])["text_column"].transform("first")
```

```
    id1  id2         text_column     standard
0  key1  220            ABC corp     ABC corp
1  key1  220         ABC Pvt Ltd     ABC corp
2  key2  300             PQR Ltd      PQR Ltd
3  key2  300                 PQR      PQR Ltd
4  key2  300  PQR something else      PQR Ltd
5  key2  400         XYZ company  XYZ company
```